# Compiler asking for return statement when one has been supplied

Tags: java

This should be the result, a little program finding the answers on the equation:

```
a*x + b*y + c*z = d
```

[image]

I'm still working on the algorithm but it asks me to give a return statement while I have one. Or does the compiler say that because it is possible the return statement doesn't get executed when the evaluation of the if-condition is false?

```
public static String zoekAlleOplossingen(int a, int b, int c, int d,
                                         int begingrens, int eindgrens) {
    int y = begingrens, z = begingrens;
    for (int x = begingrens; x < eindgrens; ++x) {
        if (((a*x) + (b*y) + (c*z)) == d) {
            return "" + a + "*" + x + " + " + b + "*" + y + " + " + c + "*" + z
               + " = " + d + "";
        }
    }
}
```

And for the people asking about why I'm using the return (someone please embed the image). Here is a UML diagram where you can clearly see it is expected in this exercise to use a String as return type in this method.:

http://i41.tinypic.com/s62a06.jpg

Comment: What happens in your function when the `if` statement doesn't get executed for the entire duration of the `for` loop? What would the function return in that case?

Comment: You don't want to have a `return` in the loop, the function will exit immediately when it's reached, unless you on;y ever want to return 1 line. It's asking you for a `return` to be placed outside the loop, because no `return` will ever be reached if you don't enter the loop and _also_ meet the condition of the `if`.

Comment: @splrs is correct. Do you plan to call this function multiple times to get the expected result? Otherwise, you should simply print out the result instead of returning it.

Comment: Some advice - Most of your question is just noise to the actual issue you're asking about. In future, you should just ask about the issue at hand. This question as an example - you can remove the function parameters, simplify the if-statement condition, for-loop bounds and return statement, and just give us that (as opposed to telling us what problem your code is intended to solve) and ask why the compiler says what it says. Also, you should include **the full, actual error message**, don't just paraphrase it. Feel free to edit this question as well - questions are here for the long run.

Comment: @bblincoe Thank you for replying. As I thought and as you guys confirm the return isn't necesseraly executed which gives the error. I know you can only return one value in a method. But is it possible to use multiple return values with the same value in one method?

Comment: @Dukeling Thanks for the advice, you are right. I did also want to ask how you guys would approach the problem (algorithm), but forgot to mention that. The full error is 'missing return statement'. Better? :)

Comment: @iPot It's best to separate these into different questions, as [so]'s format doesn't really support these being in the same question well - each question can have 1 'accepted' answer, which indicates the answer that solved the asker's problem best. If each question deals with multiple issues, there won't necessarily be an answer that addresses everything, thus there can't really be 1 accepted answer.

Comment: Ok thanks. The downvotes don't really help the questioning :) You do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*"Or does the compiler say that because it is possible the return statement doesn't get executed when the evaluation of the if-condition is false?"*

Correct, the compiler wants always to have some return statement, even if the condition fails. That's why you get this compilation problem.

Comment: You are the only guy answering my exact question. Hence my "bad" post. Thanks. I have a second question now though :)

Answer (score 0):

If your `if` statement is not evaluated to true, then you don't ever get to a return statement. You need to add one that handles the case when your `if` statement evaluates to false.

```
public static String zoekAlleOplossingen(int a, int b, int c, int d, int begingrens, int eindgrens){
int y=begingrens,z=begingrens;
for (int x=begingrens;x<eindgrens;++x){
    if ( ((a*x)+(b*y)+(c*z))==d){
        return ""+a+"*"+x+" + "+b+"*"+y+" + "+c+"*"+z+" = "+d+"";
    }
    return "Didn't Work"; //Add a default return string here
}
```

}

Comment: Thank you for mentioning you can use multiple return as long as you have the same type of data in a method. Didn't know that.

Answer (score 0):

You have one return statement BUT it only executes when the if condition is met. So, there are times when the execution will lead to no returning. The compiler is noticing and does not let you do it wrong. Try this instead:

```
public static String zoekAlleOplossingen(int a, int b, int c, int d, int begingrens, int eindgrens){
int y=begingrens,z=begingrens;
String output="";
boolean isFirst=true;
for (int x=begingrens;x<eindgrens;++x){
    if ( ((a*x)+(b*y)+(c*z))==d){
        if(isFirst){
          isFirst=false;
        }else{
          output+="\n";
        }
        output+= ""+a+"*"+x+" + "+b+"*"+y+" + "+c+"*"+z+" = "+d+"";
    }
 }
 return output;
}
```

That's the simple answer to your question. Now the tips.

In general it's wise to have a single way out from your methods. It eases the pain of debugging. So even if you see other programmers code with multiple returns try to avoid it.

If you are concatenating strings. Use StringBuilder instead as it performs better.

```
StringBuilder buffer=new StringBuilder();
buffer.append(a)
  .append("*")
  .append(x)
  .append("+")
  .append(b)
  .append("*")
  .append(y)
  .append("+")
  .append(c)
  .append("*")
  .append(z)
  .append("=")
  .append(d);
```

I guess you are trying to be able to notice at single sight, maybe because you are printing the string, that the condition is met. I would write the method as follows and do the for loop outside.

```
public static String zoekAlleOplossingen(int a, int b, int c, int d, int begingrens, int eindgrens){
int y=begingrens,z=begingrens;
StringBuilder buffer=new StringBuilder();
buffer.append(a)
  .append("*")
  .append(x)
  .append("+")
  .append(b)
  .append("*")
  .append(y)
  .append("+")
  .append(c)
  .append("*")
  .append(z)
  .append("=")
  .append(d);
   buffer.append("; is ").append((a*x)+(b*y)+(c*z)==d));
   return buffer.toString();
}
```

Finally, more than probably that piece of code is for testing. When you have some spare time take a look at JUnit.You wont have to print that out again.

NOTE: for all code, please check well formedness, I have written inline in the stackoverflow editor with no validation.

Comment: As far as I know, the optimizer's likely to convert OP's code to use a `StringBuilder` in any way, so the excessive amount of additional code that you have to write to force a `StringBuilder` to be used is probably unnecessary. Also, perhaps more significantly, the don't optimize early - just do things the easy way first, and **if performance is a problem for that piece of code**, optimize it. You're probably mostly just wasting your time by converting string concatenation to `StringBuilder`.

Comment: Guess that for that piece of code you don't need neither optimization, or a single exit or JUnit. But when I start with new stuff I like to be pointed in the right directions. Thats why all that was posted as tips and not the main response. In any case, these are zero effort things that make your work better. Don't you think so?

Comment: @dceredo I know JUnit but we do not use it in this exercise as requested by the teacher. As you say I generally want a direction and tips instead of optimization, since I'm in my first half year of these classes. I never heard iof StringBuilder etc.. but thanks for the tip to avoid multiple returns :)

Comment: Sure, it's good to point out such things, but they should also go with a disclaimer (such as my previous comment). Though I wouldn't really call using `StringBuilder` for string concatenation or setting up JUnit tests "zero effort". And single exit is not something I'd apply everywhere, although some disagree - sometimes there's a negligible benefit and it actually hurts readability.